# What can I do about a corrupt NAR info file?

Tags: nixos, corruption

I seem to have corrupted a NAR info file. I think a process got killed while writing to them. Whenever I ask nix for something it spits back an error about a corrupt NAR info file. For example:

```
$ nix-shell -p vim
error (ignored): NAR info file '3k69hbxg...sxf3.narinfo' is corrupt
error: NAR info file 'r4yn8m...7rcv.narinfo' is corrupt.
```

It does complain about different files depending on what I am trying to do.

My instinct is to just delete the corrupt files, but

1. I can't seem to find them. (I ran a `find` on my entire drive and it came up empty.)
2. I don't know what they do so I don't if they are safe to delete.

What and where are these? What can I do about their corruption?

Comment: Run the commmand with multiple `-v` for more info

Comment: `narinfo` is a metadata format for files that are downloaded from a binary cache. Could you post the full hashes?